# how to fetch data from google app engine datastore in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

i'm new to google app engine and i follow it's documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ carefully.Now I've  successfully stored my data on google app engine store by creating web application in eclipse for example i store first and last name of employee at GAE store like

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();


Entity employee = new Entity("Employee");

employee.setProperty("firstName", "Antonio");
employee.setProperty("lastName", "Salieri");

Date hireDate = new Date();
employee.setProperty("hireDate", hireDate);

employee.setProperty("attendedHrTraining", true);


datastore.put(employee);
```

and i've also deployed my project to GAE but now i want to get that stored data from data store in my android app.
is this possible to do that.
any help would me much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There different approaches to this problem. Usually you would create some kind of services, most likely in JSON format and then you'll be able to interact from your Android app with Google App Engine using HTTP requests. Even better solution though would be to use the [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/overview):

> Google Cloud Endpoints consists of tools, libraries and capabilities
>   that allow you to generate Endpoints and client libraries from an App
>   Engine backend to simplify client access to that web app. Endpoints
>   makes it easier to create a web backend for web clients and mobile
>   clients such as Android or Apple's iOS.

Comment: thanks for the reply! but i've done this job by creating new servlet which fetches data from data store and then return that data,i've use url of that servlet in app to get that data response.Thanks again!

Comment: This may be helpful for the rest who come here. Basically you can write a java servlet to communicate with your app-id.appspot.com, or cloud endpoints (which supposedly simplifies things). http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2014/06/new-ways-to-connect-your-app-to-the-cloud-android-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Query q = new Query("Student");

        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);


        for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) 
{

        String nm=(String)entity.getProperty("Name");
        String em=(String)entity.getProperty("E-Mail");
    }
     resp.getWriter().println((String)entity.getProperty("Name"));

          resp.getWriter().println((String)entity.getProperty("E-Mail"));
```